# Ruby can't link with MS C runtime (msvcr90.dll)

Tags: ruby, thin, msvcr90d.dll

I was attempting to run the Ruby Thin demo application on Windows/XP when I got an error that Windows couldn't find "msvcr90.dll" for Ruby 1.8.7 -- I found a redistributable and put that in my path to be confronted with the information that:

```
"R6034 ... application has made an attempt to lead the C runtime incorrectly"
```

Earlier today I ran a few eventmachine demos oK, so I am thinking that the problem is with Thin.

The Ruby stack dump isn't that helpful ... (included below).  Is there a cure?

I've looked over the other MSVCR90.DLL posts, none of those cures work.  The MSVCR90.DLL is now in system32 -- With the "incorrectly linked" error.

Thanks in advance.

... Will

```
------
W:\> ruby adapter.rb
>> Thin web server (v1.2.2 codename I Find Your Lack of Sauce Disturbing)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 127.0.0.1:3000, CTRL+C to stop
c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib/thin_parser.so: 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.  
    - c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib/thin_parser.so (LoadError)
      from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
      from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib/thin/request.rb:1
      from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:35:in `post_init'
      from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.8-x86-mswin32-60/lib/em/connection.rb:43:in `new'
      from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.8-x86-mswin32-60/lib/em/connection.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.8-x86-mswin32-60/lib/em/connection.rb:36:in `new'
    from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.8-x86-mswin32-60/lib/eventmachine.rb:1490:in `event_callback'
    from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.8-x86-mswin32-60/lib/eventmachine.rb:242:in `run_machine'
    from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.8-x86-mswin32-60/lib/eventmachine.rb:242:in `run'
    from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
    from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start!'
    from c:/bin/ruby/v1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib/thin/server.rb:142:in `start'
    from adapter.rb:21
```

Answer (score 0):

appears to be that you need to exclude the /MD parameter
and make sure your library calls xfree, not free :)

http://groups.google.com/group/thin-ruby/browse_thread/thread/c15b2472eb97c2ba/ea7c5127035d193b
-r

Comment: Hi there ...

thaks I figured that about /MD before.  Can you expand on what is xfree?  The target here is Windows/XP, the only "xfree" I'm switched on to is the x-windows pac.

Please see: THIN-RUBY thread

http://groups.google.com/group/thin-ruby/browse_thread/thread/c15b2472eb97c2ba/b2497f846f1190a8?lnk=gst&q=link#b2497f846f1190a8

Where I lose traction, because the ultimate answer is mingw.

Not to worry.

There are some helpful comments.  I found that the config.h and rbconfig.rb ar vital to resolving this. With today's builds.

Get out there and make ruby compiler FREE!! 

\_w_/

Comment: xfree is ruby's wrapper to the free method--calling it instead of free will make it possible to run your code "cross msvcrt.dll" [i.e. you link to one, run it in another], or so I'm told.http://programming-gone-awry.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-compile-using-visual-studio-for.html

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby 1.9 this appears to be getting resolved with the (*Windows*) [RubyInstaller DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit), caveat it is still a work in progress.

- http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit

Harking back to the original issue, the build will depend on which compiler the Ruby you are using was built with, etc.  Even with the current [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit) things aren't 100%.  I had a few builds fail.  So there's definite sensitivity to your environment.

Good luck.